# 2 cliques para abrir o popover novamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou criando um `popopver` no qual inseri nele um botão de fechar. Como mostra abaixo na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown" style="float: right;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs popover-markup" data-placement="bottom" style="margin-right: 10px">Preferências</button>
  <div class="head hide">Opção do cliente <a  class="close" href="#");">&times;</a></div>
  <div class="content hide">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkbox-avatar-store"> Lojas do cliente<br>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" class="checkbox-competition"> Lojas concorrentes<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.popover-markup').popover({
    html: true,
    title: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.head').html();
    },
    content: function () {
        return $(this).parent().find('.content').html();
    }
}).on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    var $popup = $(this);
    $(this).next('.popover').find('a.close').click(function (e) {
        $popup.popover('hide');
    });
});
```

Após ele ser fechado usando o método `popover('hide')`, como é mostrado no código acima, só é possível abrir novamente clicando 2 vezes no botão <kbd>Preferências</kbd>. Por quê? Não deveria abrir dando apenas 1 clique? Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 0):

Altere a utilização `$popup.popover('hide')` por `$popup.popover('toggle')`.

Adicione o seguinte codigo no seu script:

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.popover', function (e) {
    $(e.target).data("bs.popover").inState = { click: false, hover: false, focus: false }
});
```

Comment: Teria como detalhar melhor sua resposta?!

Comment: Tem sim, tente ao inves de utilizar o $popup.popover('hide'); substituir por $popup.popover('toggle'); para verificar se o problema continua

Comment: Isso não resolveu.

Comment: @white adicione no seu codigo o item que alterei a cima na resposta e veja se resolve seu problema